# How to delete a selected item from isolated storage? The user gives the name for the file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I am able to save it in isolated storage and retrieve it. But how to delete?

```
private void Deleting(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult message = MessageBox.Show("The Files will be permanently deleted.","Continue?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (message == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isofile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            isofile.DeleteFile("//What to do here?");

        }

        else if (message == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)            

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MyRecordings.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Comment: Just give `DeleteFile` path to the file you have. The very same path you used when saving of retrieving the file, that is.

Comment: If you're having issues using the built in isolated storage lib check out this free DLL I wrote. It's a wrapper around isolated storage that makes saving retrieving and deleting as single call. http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=47

Comment: Thank you jlahd. I am saving and retrieving directly from the long list selector. However for deleting I am using the context menu. So how to call a function via a button event handler

Comment: Yes AMR I shall make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Windows Phone Toolkit context menu, you should be able to get the data you need from the sender object, e.g.

```
var selected = sender as MenuItem;
```

See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/05/19/windows-phone-toolkit-context-menu-getting-selected-item-within-a-long-list-selector.aspx

Pass the file path to the DeleteFile method to delete a file. You should really check if the file exists first and dispose of the isoFile object when finished with it:

```
using (var isofile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 {
     if (isofile.FileExists("foo.txt"))
     {
          isofile.DeleteFile("foo.txt");
     }
 }
```